# Difference between using SUM(column = "xxx") and COUNT() with WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a bit confused about why I got a different answer by using SUM(column = "xxx") and COUNT() with WHERE.  Their logic looks the same to me...

In case you guys want some background of the problem:

[image]

**My query that got the wrong answer:**

```
WITH clicked AS(
SELECT ad_id, COUNT(action) AS c_cnt
FROM Ads
WHERE action = "clicked"
GROUP BY ad_id),

viewed AS(
SELECT ad_id, COUNT(action) AS v_cnt
FROM Ads
WHERE action = "Viewed"
GROUP BY ad_id),

total AS(
SELECT ad_id, c_cnt/(c_cnt+v_cnt)*100 AS ctr
FROM clicked
JOIN viewed
USING(ad_id)
GROUP BY ad_id)

SELECT DISTINCT ad_id, IFNULL(ROUND(ctr,2),0) AS ctr
FROM Ads
LEFT JOIN total
USING(ad_id)
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1 ASC
```

**My query that got the right answer:**

```
WITH clicked AS(
SELECT ad_id, SUM(action = "Clicked") AS c_cnt
FROM Ads
GROUP BY ad_id),

viewed AS(
SELECT ad_id, SUM(action = "Viewed") AS v_cnt
FROM Ads
GROUP BY ad_id),

total AS(
SELECT ad_id, c_cnt/(c_cnt+v_cnt)*100 AS ctr
FROM clicked
JOIN viewed
USING(ad_id)
GROUP BY ad_id)

SELECT DISTINCT ad_id, IFNULL(ROUND(ctr,2),0) AS ctr
FROM Ads
LEFT JOIN total
USING(ad_id)
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1 ASC
```

The only different part is the part I highlighted in yellow:
[image]

[image]

The picture is the test case that my first query did not pass.

Comment: Both query get same results?

Comment: Hi! The second query passed all the test case while the first query failed the test case (Last picture)

Comment: I wonder how they know that an ad was ignored. Scary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important difference between those two options is:

- if you use `count() ... where ...` , only ad_ids that have a row with that property will be part of the resultset (e.g. all results will have a `x_cnt`-value > 0).
- if you use `SUM(action = "xxx")`, all ad_ids will be part of the resultset, but some will have the `x_cnt`-value 0.

Your `total`-resultset now does a `join`, e.g. the `where`-option will remove specifically those ad_ids that are in `clicked` but not in `viewed` (e.g. which would have `v_cnt = 0`). Those are the ones with a 100% conversion rate, which in turn will give you the wrong result in your final step, where those will show as 0% (as they are not in the `total`-resultset).

You can fix your solution by using a `left join`:

```
total AS( 
  SELECT ad_id, c_cnt/(c_cnt+IFNULL(v_cnt,0))*100 AS ctr
  FROM clicked
  LEFT JOIN viewed
  USING(ad_id)
  GROUP BY ad_id, c_cnt, v_cnt)
```

Now the cases "v_cnt = 0, c_cnt > 0" are part of the `total`-resultset.

Note that this only works as expected as the correct result for "v_cnt > 0, c_cnt = 0" is 0. Those cases won't be part of the `total`-resultset, but your final `select` handles those since you use `left join total` and `IFNULL(ctr,0)`. If you wanted (or in a situation where `0` isn't the right correction), you could include them to your `total`-resultset by using a [full outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4796872/6248528) (e.g. `... clicked left join viewed ...  union ... viewed left join clicked ...`).

Speaking of edge cases, the `SUM`-option has one too: for "v_cnt = 0, c_cnt = 0" (e.g. ad_id 5), your division `/(c_cnt+v_cnt)` will fail. Although MySQL will handle this (by setting it `null`), and you in turn handle MySQLs handling of it (by making it 0 in `IFNULL(ctr,0)`), you may want to be aware of it.

Comment: Thank you so so much for the explanation!  It helps a beginner like me a lot!